# Wrong number of indices inside, expected 2

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I don't understand why I am getting this error because my multi-dimensional array should function fine but it isn't working in this case due to the listed error...I am very frustrated.

error is: `Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2`

This is what I have:

```
    public static void DisplayTopScore(string username, double score)
    {


        string[] highscores = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

        string[,] Temphighscores = new string[10, 2];
        string[] TempScoresToSplit;

        int counter=0;




        foreach (string highScore in highscores)
        {

            TempScoresToSplit = highScore.Split(' ');

          Temphighscores[counter][0]=  TempScoresToSplit[0];
           Temphighscores[counter][1]= TempScoresToSplit[1];


           counter++;
        }

  }


    }
```

The place where it says wrong number of indices are at these 2 lines:

```
  Temphighscores[counter][0]=  TempScoresToSplit[0];
   Temphighscores[counter][1]= TempScoresToSplit[1];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
Temphighscores[counter, 0] = TempScoresToSplit[1];
Temphighscores[counter, 1] = TempScoresToSplit[1];
```

instead.

The [MSDN article on multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) is probably worth a read.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I confused this with some other array that I learned.

Comment: I was also confused, because in C++ it works like this